# To get pointer to CWnd of dialog form

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have MFC application with `CSrvDlg` dialog form as main window:

```
    BOOL CSrvApp::InitInstance()
    {
        CWinApp::InitInstance();
        CSrvDlg SrvDlg; 
...
        INT_PTR nResponse = SrvDlg.DoModal();
    }
```

I need to create child dialog forms. But for this reason I need to get pointer to `CWnd` of main form to pass for constructor parameter like pointer to parent window. How to get pointer to `CWnd` of my `SrvDlg` form?

Comment: I believe you have the answer from @S. Sashida. But you should explain this in more detail. Once you create a modal dialog, you can't do anything from outside the dialog until the user clicks OK/Cancel. I am not sure what you plan to do with that handle.

Comment: If you're creating the child dialogs from your main form like your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636634/mfc-dialog-form-freezes) of today implies, then you would pass the `this` pointer because a CDialog is a CWnd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because CSrvDlg is a child class of CWnd, you can get CWnd* pointer by

```
CWnd* ptr = &SrvDlg;
```

or explicitly

```
CWnd* ptr = static_cast<CWnd*>(&SrvDlg);
```